# Updating an Array of Objects (Mongoose Schema) - Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

This is my Room Schema `room.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = mongoose.model(config.DATA_TYPE.ROOM, new Schema({
    name: String,
    guide: String,
    leader: String,
    partecipants_counter : { type: Number, default: 0},
    event_counter : { type: Number, default: 0},
    creation: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    partecipants: [],
    events: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: config.DATA_TYPE.EVENT}]
}));
```

And this is my Event Schema `event.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = mongoose.model(config.DATA_TYPE.EVENT, new Schema({
    id: Number,
    data: String,
    user: String,
    post: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, { _id: false }));
```

This 2 schemas are in the `/app/models/` folder, while my manager script is in `/app/managers/` folder. My manager contains the following code:

```
...
var Room = require('../models/room.js');
var Event = require('../models/event.js');
...
    createRoom: function(name,leader,guide,callback){
        new Room({
            name: name,
            guide: guide,
            leader: leader,
            partecipants : [guide,leader],
            partecipants_counter : 2
        }).save(callback);
    },
...
    pushEvent(roomId,eventData,sign,callback){
        this.getRoomById(roomId,function(err,data){
            if(sign == data.leader || sign == data.guide ){
                var new_event = {
                    id: data.event_counter,
                    data: eventData,
                    user: sign
                }

                Room.update(
                    { "_id" : roomId},
                    { $inc  : { event_counter : +1 },
                      $push : { events:
                                    { id : new_event.id,
                                      data : new_event.data,
                                      user : new_event.user
                                    }
                              } 
                    },function(err,data){
                            callback(err,new_event);
                    });
            }else{
                err = 1;
                callback(err);
            }
        });

    },
...
```

The `new_event` is correctly created but my `update-query` doesn't work, everything behave as expected but my database doesn't receive any update: I can't create any event.

Comment: Can you confirm `getRoomById` is getting called? Since you're using `this` it could be the your not binding the function correctly.

Comment: Yes I do confirm, it is working since the `if(sign == data.leader || sign == data.guide)` is true and the `new_event` is correctly created.